# I have to upload a binary type in retrofit POST api . How can i do that?

Tags: android, retrofit2

@Multipart
@POST("user_trial_ocr")
Call getOcr(@Query("service") String dl, @Part MultipartBody.Part  file0 );

RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file0);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image/jpeg",file0.getName(), requestFile);
Call call=jsonPlaceHolderApi.getOcr(image,body);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the issue was i need to send image to backend in binary and i was facing problem what to send inside content header

Answer (score 0):

That kotlin code may helps you.

```
val requestFile: RequestBody =
    RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull(), file)

val requestBody: RequestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
    .addFormDataPart("name", "param1")
    .addFormDataPart("fathername", "param2")
    .addFormDataPart("cnic", "88")
    .addFormDataPart("rollno", "2")
    .addFormDataPart("image", "image",requestFile)
    .build()
```

make abstract function in interface like that

```
@POST("v1/addstudentinfo")
fun sendStudentData(@Body req:RequestBody): Call<StudentInfoResponse>
```